# how can i post my form data in aws dynamoDb unsing json & nodejs

Tags: javascript, database, json, node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    req.pipe(process.stdout);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    req.pipe(res);
  }
  else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);`enter code here`
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: But how can i put my data to AWS dynamo Db using node and JSon want a sample code ..... is anybody suggest me

Comment: robertklep@ do you have any example

Comment: https://npmjs.org/search?q=dynamodb

Comment: robertklep@ dude i just go through it but the phase where am facing problem is...1).if reg.method=post then how my form data will be posted to aws dynamo db ......2).how to use json ..........dude you are so experience it will take 5-6 min if you just mail me an example ankigujjar@gmail.com